# Load balancing and failover using nmcli

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, networkmanager, nmcli

I would like to use nmcli (NetworkManager, on CentOS) to balance the load from the subnet 172.22.0.0/24 across the two gateways (.3 and .1) on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. These two gateways are connected to two different ISP commercial fiber-optic routers. The network looks like this:

[image: network diagram]

And the three NICs on `balancerouter` look like this:

```
===============================================================================
                            Device details (enp2s0)
===============================================================================
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.22/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.3
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.3, mt = 101
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 101
IP4.DNS[1]:                             9.9.9.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

===============================================================================
                            Device details (enp1s0)
===============================================================================
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.22.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.22.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             9.9.9.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

===============================================================================
                            Device details (enp3s0)
===============================================================================
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.23/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 102
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 102
IP4.DNS[1]:                             9.9.9.9
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

At the moment all traffic from 172.22.0.0/24 is routed through 192.168.1.3, because (I believe) the mt (metric) value is lower than that of 192.168.1.1.

Can I use nmcli to 'load balance' traffic from 172.22.0.0/24 between 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.3 and to ensure failover if one of the ISP routers stops working?